# Blue Screen Bug in build (Screen position out of view frustum)

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game and everything runs okay on the editor, but when I build the game on Android and ios platforms, sometimes the screen goes into blue and I receive this error:[image]

```
Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 690.000000, 808.000000) (Camera rect 0 0 828 1792)
UnityEngine.Camera:ScreenPointToRay(Vector2, MonoOrStereoscopicEye)
UnityEngine.Camera:ScreenPointToRay(Vector3, MonoOrStereoscopicEye)
UnityEngine.Camera:ScreenPointToRay(Vector3)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)
```

And Sometimes this one:

```
Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 675.000000, 167.000137) (Camera rect 0 0 1170 2532)
UnityEngine.RectTransformUtility:PointInRectangle(Vector2, RectTransform, Camera, Vector4)
UnityEngine.UI.GraphicRaycaster:Raycast(Canvas, Camera, Vector2, IList`1, List`1)
UnityEngine.UI.GraphicRaycaster:Raycast(PointerEventData, List`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:RaycastAll(PointerEventData, List`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerInputModule:GetTouchPointerEventData(Touch, Boolean&, Boolean&)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
```

The error keeps appearing in every frame with different screen positions.

I've also included an explanation of my project if you want to understand it better:
My project's scale is too big, and everything is 50 times bigger than a normal object so I've been forced to set the far clip to 6000. I'm using virtual cameras that instantiate during playtime. Doozy UI and Lean touch + are used in the project, as well as Lean joystick from the Lean GUI package. The lights are baked and we have a light probe on the scene. My unity version is 2020.3.21f1. And the project is not Hololens or VR.

I've read everything on the internet about this issue and done whatever I could but my problem still remains.
Here is what I've done so far:

1. Remove the camera's tag and make it "Untaged"
2. Increase camera's a near clip
3. Debug camera rect, camera scale, FOV, near clip, far clip but noneof
   them change when the bug occurs
4. Removed cinemachine from my project
5. Make sure that my camera does not instantiate during run time
6. Make sure that the main scene added to the build setting
7. Remove the main camera and create another one
8. Remove light baking and light probe
9. Remove every light from the scene
10. Downgrade the unity to 2019.4.28f1

I think the problem may be from lean touch, especially the joystick script.
There are some functions like
`RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint`
and `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle`
that I'm suspicious to them and tried to check the pointer and screen values before calling them but it didn't help also.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: `everything is 50 times bigger than a normal object` why? ^^ Is your camera size somewhere changed and maybe set to `0`?

Comment: Because of some assets we use in our project, we need everything to be that big.
I've also debugged the camera size but it's not changing when errors occur. And the main camera is in perspective mode.